# Are these structural issues or just common settling cracks? Older home built in 1972

Tags: repair, drywall, wood, walls, doors

[image]

[image]

[image]

See pics above. Small but just want to make sure these are normal.

Comment: I would say not unusual but cracks can be caused with big temp swings (the ones at the tape lines /seams). It could also be the tell tail signs of a problem with a structure. Are they all on the same wall or at different locations in the home. If all on the same wall I would be checking the framework and foundation on that wall, of no problems are found or these are old cracks not just appearing it could be classed as settling. If new really check things out or hire an inspector to look for you.